# How to run/execute remote scripts locally using powershell scipt

Tags: shell, powershell

Steps:

## 1. I have created a file known as: "test.vbs" under temp folder in machine B and in that script i have msgbox "hi"

## 2. From machine A - my goal is execute to test.vbs in machine B

## 3. In machine A. i did the following steps but i didnt get remote script executed. Can anyone please help me.

ps c:/> $s=new -pssession -computername machineB
ps c:/> Invoke-Command -Session $s-ScriptBlock{$filecount=(Get-ChildItem c:\temp\test.vbs -Recurse)}
ps c:/> Invoke-Command -Session $s-ScriptBlock{$filecount}

i received directory c:\temp and a file name as test.vbs

Now i want to execute test.vbs

ps c:/> Invoke-Command -ComputerName MachineB{& "C:\Temp\test.vbs"}

After executing the above command i dont see the test.vbs not executing remotely.
my expectation is to get hi messagebox.

I am not understanding if it got executed or not.

can anyone please help me to execute remote script locally using power shell.

thanks inadvance.

Comment: Put the script in a shared folder which you can access from your local machine. Then just execute it, e.g. like this: `\\remotemachine\sharedfolder\script.ps1`

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding to your question is correct, you want to execute test.vbs against machine B from machine A, I don't think it's possible in PowerShell.

I faced the same issue some time ago. Neither Enter-PsSession nor Invoke-Command can do it for you probably just because they are not designed for this purpose. They are working totally fine if you run any PowerShell cmdlets remotely e.g. Get-Item you can easily get items on machine B. But once if you try to do something beyond the PowerShell remote session, like run a vbs script which will start a new CScript.exe process, it just won't work. It's due to some reason in underlying implementation of this PowerShell remoting.

If you do need to do that, I got two workarounds

1. [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) can be the best solution. It was designed to do this kind of work originally and it can easily accomplish what you want with a bunch of advanced features.
2. Create a scheduled task on machine B by using [New-ScheduledTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps) and let it trigger itself on machine B locally.
3. If you have SCCM installed, it also provides this kind of functionality, check out [this blog](http://gerryhampsoncm.blogspot.co.id/2013/03/sccm-2012-sp1-step-by-step-guide-part_20.html).

Comment: Your understanding on my problem is correct. for #1. I agree that PSEXEC will be helpful and i have worked on that earlier but current  company doesnot support in downloading PSExec., so thats y i m looking for powershell option. #2. Not a right choice for my situation because MachineB is a VM image and it expires for every 7 days. #3.i have gone through the link you have sgared for SCCM, basically it showed to install software silently remotely but my requirement is different wherein i need to execute remote scripts locally.